# Sending image + Data ajax post to ashx handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ashx

How could i send Image + Some json object Data to ashx handler??
Is it possible in jquery ajax post??

Like this:

```
         var fileUpload = $("#image").get(0);
            var files = fileUpload.files;

            var imag = new FormData();
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                imag.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
            }



            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../Scripts/uploadify/UploadHandler.ashx",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: "image=" + imag + "&Data=" + JSON.stringify({ objEnt: args }),
                success: function(){

                }

            });
```

Can we do like this??

Comment: After you append all your files to the `FormData` object you created just do another append for your json data `imag.append('Data', JSON.stringify({ objEnt: args }))`. Then set the `data:` of the ajax request just to `imag`.

Comment: But it m8 become much complexity while reading from context.request in ashx

Comment: It should not be any different than what you're trying to do here. The way you're trying isn't possible. You can't send a `FormData` object in a query string as data with jQuery's `ajax`. The `FormData` must be the only thing in the `data` parameter. Reading the data from the request is the same as you would with any other, by key.

Comment: I will add this an the answer to this question then so we can close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you append all your files to the `FormData` object you created just do another append for your json data `imag.append('Data', JSON.stringify({ objEnt: args }))`. Then set the `data:` of the ajax request just to `imag`.

```
var fileUpload = $("#image").get(0);
var files = fileUpload.files;

var imag = new FormData();
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    imag.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
}

imag.append('Data', JSON.stringify({ objEnt: args }));


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../Scripts/uploadify/UploadHandler.ashx",
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: imag,
    success: function(){

    }

});
```

Comment: Btw @Adam can i return a string (filename) from ashx to my success function??

Comment: @user3640046 sure, just change the success function to `success: function(fileName){` and then server side after the upload is done just echo the name.